# How to troubleshoot DHCP Pi-hole connectivity issues?

Tags: networking, pi-4, dhcp, pi-hole

I have a Pi 4 (4GB) with Raspberry Pi OS. I have installed Pi-hole.

The Raspberry PI IP: 192.168.0.5

The Router IP: 192.168.0.1

I set the DHCP range in Pi-hole to 192.168.0.2 to 192.168.0.254 (which was my router's original settings)

The Router (gateway) IP address to 192.168.0.1

The router does not allow for custom DNS so I went the DHCP route.

I then enabled "DHCP server enabled". [image]

I then disabled DHCP on my router [image]
I then reset the router and all devices on the network.

However, my devices cannot find the DHCP server, they assign themselves a 169.XXX.XXX.XXX.

If I manually configure a static IP from each device, the device connects to pihole and works as expected.

**What steps can I take to ensure the router talks with Pi-hole and the DHCP server to assign IP's on the network?**
*I am a new student, so having the commands written out to troubleshoot would be a big help!

Comment: Without knowing what you did when you modified the script folk are going to be stuck to help. I would ask this on the pi-hole forum https://discourse.pi-hole.net/ as it's not actually a Pi problem (pi-hole runs on lots of systems inc the Pi). Voting to close for this reason.

Comment: From what you describe I'd guess you have a DNS issue not a DHCP one. From the screenshot your router issued DHCP leases for a week. Until those leases expire I wouldn't expect the pi to start issuing leases. You say the issue is no Internet after disconnecting and reconnecting a device? If you can connect to the network DHCP is working fine, if devices on the network can't then reach the Internet that suggest a DNS issue. I'd start your search there.

Comment: The devices on the network assign themselves a 169.XXX.XXX.XXX IP. I guess this is the IP used when the DHCP server is down, or the device cannot properly connect. If I manually set the IP from the device, the device connects to the internet and is listed as a client on the Pi-hole dashboard.

Comment: Is the pi-hole box connected via Ethernet or WiFi? Are the devices connected by WiFi or Ethernet?  If both are WiFi does your router stop WiFi to WiFi connection (sometimes known as client isolation)? Is the Pi actually connected to the network (i.e. can you ping google.com and 8.8.8.8 from it)?

Comment: The pi is connected to Ethernet. All devices are connected via WiFi. The pi is connected to the internet (I just pinged google.com and 8.8.8.8 and got data back)